# How to write the output of this code to HTML file?

Tags: python

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

from urllib import urlopen

class Spider(HTMLParser):

        def __init__(self, url):
                HTMLParser.__init__(self)
                req = urlopen(url)
                self.feed(req.read())

        def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
                if tag == 'a' and attrs:
                        print "Found link => %s" % attrs[0][1]

Spider('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python')
```

Comment: How can I do that in one script?

Answer (score 3):

```
python spider.py > output.html
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this at the top of your script:

```
import sys
sys.stdout = file('output.html', 'w')
```

This will redirect everything your script writes to the standard output (which includes `print` statements) to the file 'output.html'.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't messed with Spider at all, but is it printing html, or are you just printing the "Found link..." lines? If you are just printing those, you can do something like `outfl = open('output.txt')`

And then, instead of `print`, call `outfl.write("Found link => %s" % attrs[0][1])`.

You can always write out `<html><head></head><body>` before, and `</body></html>` after it if you're needing it in HTML format. Also, use `outfl = open('output.html')` instead of .txt for the filename.

Did I totally miss the question here? If you want better answers, you ought to describe the question a little better.